# Add extra level of nesting to existing data?

Tags: mongodb

In my database, I have data that lives in a single level structure. However, I have recently made changes and I now need to convert one of the properties to a nested object for existing data.

What is the best way to query and update these existing records?

Old structure:

```
{
  "id": "xxx",
  "address": {
    "city": "Some City",
    "state": "AK",
    "zip": "55555"
  },
  "type": "customer"
}
```

New structure (need to update the old structure to look like this)

```
{
  "id": "xxx",
  "address": {
    "current": {
      "city": "Some City",
      "state": "AK",
      "zip": "55555"
    }
  },
  "type": "customer"
}
```

In the above example, I want to update everyone's address to add the extra layer of nesting with the `current` property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need [Update with aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/#update-with-an-aggregation-pipeline).

1. `$set` - Set `address.current` field with `address` value.
2. `$unset` - Remove `city`, `state`, `zip` fields from `address` field.

```
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    $set: {
      "address.current": "$address"
    }
  },
  {
    $unset: [
      "address.city",
      "address.state",
      "address.zip"
    ]
  }
],
{
  multi: true
})
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Tn0VUA86llc)